# Получить ArrayList<Valute> из AsyncTask и передать его в другую активность

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, android-asynctask

ArrayList - лист хранящий объекты класса Valute. При выходе из AsyncTask он оказывается пустым. Как сохранить информацию в нем и затем передать в другую активность?

**В doInBackground** получаю json валют.
**В onPostExecute** - парсинг json, добавление данных в ArrayList и заполнение listView и отдельного поле для даты *dateTextView*

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ListView listValute;
private TextView dateValute;

String url = "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js";

ArrayList<Valute> arrayValute = new ArrayList<Valute>();
String[] majorCurrency = null;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_convert) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConvertActivity.class);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("valute", arrayValute);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    dateValute = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataValute);
    new ProgressTask().execute();
}

class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpHandler htppHandler = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonString = htppHandler.makeServiceCall(url);
        return jsonString;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonString);

        majorCurrency = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.majorCurrency);
        String dateTextView = null;

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            String jsonDate = jsonObj.getString("Date");
            dateTextView = modifyDateLayout(jsonDate);
            Log.d("DATE_VALUTE", dateTextView);

            JSONObject valuteJSON = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Valute");

            for (int i = 0; i < majorCurrency.length; i++) {
                JSONObject c = valuteJSON.getJSONObject(majorCurrency[i]);
                String numCode = c.getString("NumCode");
                String charCode = c.getString("CharCode");
                String name = c.getString("Name");
                String value = c.getString("Value");
                String previous = c.getString("Previous");

                Valute valute = new Valute(numCode, charCode, name, value, previous);
                //Log.d("l", "doInBackground: " + valute.toString());
                arrayValute.add(valute);
            }
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("JSON_Error", "Json parsing error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Log.v("Exception", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        dateValute.setText(dateTextView);
        listValute = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listValute);
        ValuteAdapter adapter = new ValuteAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, arrayValute);
        listValute.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

private String modifyDateLayout(String inputDate) throws ParseException {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(inputDate);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);
}}
```

ConvertActivity

```
public class ConvertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ArrayList<Valute> valuteArrayList = (ArrayList<Valute>)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("valute");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < valuteArrayList.size() ; i++)
        Log.d("value is" , valuteArrayList.get(i).toString());
}
}
```

Valute

```
public class Valute implements Parcelable {
private String vNumCode;//ISO Цифровой код валюты
private String vCharCode;//ISO Символьный код валюты
private String vName; //название
private String vValue; //последнее значение курса
private String vPrevious; // предыдущее значение курса

public Valute(String vNumCode, String vCharCode, String vName, String vValue, String vPrevious) {
    this.vNumCode = vNumCode;
    this.vCharCode = vCharCode;
    this.vName = vName;
    this.vValue = vValue;
    this.vPrevious = vPrevious;
}

public Valute(Parcel source) {
    vNumCode = source.readString();
    vCharCode = source.readString();
    vName = source.readString();
    vValue = source.readString();
    vPrevious = source.readString();
}

public String getNumCode() {
    return vNumCode;
}
public void setNumCode(String numCode) {
    vNumCode = numCode;
}

public String getCharCode() {
    return vCharCode;
}
public void setCharCode(String charCode) {
    vCharCode = charCode;
}

public String getName() {
    return vName;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    vName = name;
}

public String getValue() { return vValue; }
public void setValue(String curs) {
    vValue = curs;
}

public String getPrevious() { return vPrevious; }
public void setPrevious(String previous) {
    vPrevious = previous;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public String toString() {
    return vName + " " + vCharCode + " " + vNumCode + " " + vValue + " " + vPrevious;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(vNumCode);
    parcel.writeString(vCharCode);
    parcel.writeString(vName);
    parcel.writeString(vValue);
    parcel.writeString(vPrevious);
}
public static final Creator<Valute> CREATOR = new Creator<Valute>(){
    @Override
    public Valute createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Valute(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Valute[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Valute[size];
    }
};}
```

При переходе на активность выдает следующее:

```
    2020-02-04 15:54:45.665 2587-2587/com.example.curcon3 W/Bundle: Key valute expected Parcelable but value was a java.util.ArrayList.  The default value <null> was returned.
    2020-02-04 15:54:45.671 2587-2587/com.example.curcon3 W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
```

**Olmicron** выдает следующую ошибку:
[image: ошибка несовместимости типов]

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Valute> valuteArrayList = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("valute");
```

Comment: выдает ошибку, добавил изображение в вопросе

Comment: @VladPech обновил ответ